# running code in ASP.NET project in server side

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET project and i need my project to run pice of code

```
void f()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //Do important thing
        }
    }
```

Where i can put my code to ensure that this code is running in any time?

Comment: This lacks information...but, it sounds like ASP.NET is not what you should be using, and rather Windows Service.  Explain the code or process you need, and I'm sure you will get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't as I know a reliable solution to run a background task on Asp.net. Due to the nature of the architecture a recycle can happen at any time killing your process.
Usually the best solution is to have an out of process app (win service,  scheduled task, ..) that do your job.

If you really need it inside asp.net maybe you can use this solution: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Basically you can use an item cache with an expiration callback to simulate a scheduled task.

As a final note consider that some hosting providers have proprietary solution that you can use to run background process.